# ESLint - Prevent importing unpublished module files

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, ecmascript-6, eslint

`mymodule/package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "mymodule",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "./src/index.js"
}
```

`myapp/app.js`

allow this

```
import 'mymodule'
```

Disallow this

```
import 'mymodule/src/_private.js'
```

Can this be done via eslint?

I found this module but it seems to be doing something related but not exactly the same. https://github.com/mysticatea/eslint-plugin-node/blob/master/docs/rules/no-unpublished-import.md

Comment: What is the definition of "unpublished" here? I guess, you would like to have only imports that have been defined as `main`.